# how can i wrap grid making it responsive?

Tags: css

I've been trying to do the last project of the FCC certificate, my problem is the mid section with the grid part, i managed to do something by trial and error, something at the end did come out, the problem is now i've been following other posts about using minmax, auto-fill and auto-fit after the repeat tag but it doesnt seem to work for me, it ruins the images blocks and they go wild if i touch something.
this is the whole code
https://jsfiddle.net/8k7ne9so/9/

```css
.works {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(320px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 18px;
  grid-row-gap: 24px;
  grid-area: auto;
}

.projects1 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

.projects2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 3 / 3 / 4;
}

.projects3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 4 / 3 / 5;
}

.projects4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2 / 4 / 3;
}

.projects5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 3 / 4 / 4;
}

.projects6 {
  grid-area: 3 / 4 / 4 / 5;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="presentation" id="presentation">
    <h1>Hi, I'm Marwan</h1>
    <p>Junior Web Developer</p>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- lavori -->
<section>
  <div id="works">

    <h2 class="text">These are all my works so far</h2>

    <div class="works">

      <a id="projects" class="projects1" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>

      <a id="projects" class="projects2" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>

      <a id="projects" class="projects3" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>

      <a id="projects" class="projects4" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>

      <a id="projects" class="projects5" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>

      <a id="projects" class="projects6" href="#">
        <img class="images" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" alt="">
        <p class="pj-title"><span class="code">&lt;</span> prova <span class="code">&#47;&gt;</span></p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

as I said I'm trying everything but I can't manage to make them wrap and center do the center page

Comment: What do you want it to look like?

Comment: https://personal-portfolio.freecodecamp.rocks/
Like the grid here